# R get html data from a javascript action

Tags: javascript, html, r

I would like to scrape some data from a page where I need to click on a button (javascript) that give me access to a table.

when your on http://www.si-vitifrance.com/docs/cvi/cvi13/cartes_inter/c_vin01_coop_com07/ you have access to a map and to the data table with a small 'table' button on the left.

It opens a new window with the results and I would like to get this result in R. The url of this new page is http://www.si-vitifrance.com/docs/cvi/cvi13/cartes_inter/c_vin01_coop_com07/embfiles/table.html?th0 but I can't have acces to this page if I don't come from the map page.

So I would like to know if it's possible to simulate with R something that produce the same effect than a click on this button to have acces to this data.

I have tried

```
path<-"http://www.si-vitifrance.com/docs/cvi/cvi13/cartes_inter/c_vin01_coop_com07/embfiles/table.html?th0"
webpage <- getURL(path)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
```

but the result obviously doesn't work

```
 [1] "ï»¿<!DOCTYPE HTML>"                                                                                                  
 [2] "<html>"                                                                                                              
 [3] "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />"                                           
 [4] "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" />"                                                                      
 [5] "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"rectable.css\" />"                                                                   
 [6] "<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">"                                                           
 [7] "<!--"                                                                                                                
 [8] "function sortTable(theColumn,datatype,orderby) {"                                                                    
 [9] "  document.getElementById(\"content\").innerHTML = \"Veuillez patientez ...\";"                                      
[10] "  var themaId = window.location.search.substr(1,window.location.search.length);"                                     
[11] "  var xslFile = \"styletable.xsl\";"                                                                                 
[12] "  window.opener.mv_loadAttrTableFile(themaId,true);"                                                                 
[13] "  try {"                                                                                                             
[14] "\ttry {"                                                                                                             
[15] "      var xslt = new ActiveXObject(\"Msxml2.XSLTemplate.4.0\");"                                                     
[16] "      var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject(\"Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.4.0\");"                                       
[17] "    } catch(e) {"                                                                                                    
[18] "      var xslt = new ActiveXObject(\"Msxml2.XSLTemplate\");"                                                         
[19] "      var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject(\"Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument\");"                                           
[20] "    }"                                                                                                               
[21] "    xslDoc.async = false;"                                                                                           
[22] "    xslDoc.resolveExternals = false;"                                                                                
[23] "    xslDoc.load(xslFile);"                                                                                           
[24] "    xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;"                                                                                       
[25] "    var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();"                                                                           
[26] "    xslProc.input = window.opener.mv_XMLFileArray[themaId].XMLFile;"                                                 
[27] "    if (theColumn) {"                                                                                                
[28] "      xslProc.addParameter(\"field\",\"f\" + (parseInt(theColumn) - 1));"                                            
[29] "      xslProc.addParameter(\"datatype\",datatype);"                                                                  
[30] "      xslProc.addParameter(\"orderby\",orderby);"                                                                    
[31] "    }"                                                                                                               
[32] "    xslProc.transform();"                                                                                            
[33] "    content.innerHTML = xslProc.output;"                                                                             
[34] "  } "                                                                                                                
[35] ""                                                                                                                    
[36] "  catch(e) {"                                                                                                        
[37] "    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor(); "                                                                       
[38] "    var xslStylesheet = window.opener.mv_loadXMLDoc(window.opener.mv_Doc.BaseURL + \"embfiles/\" + xslFile,\"xml\");"
[39] "    try {"                                                                                                           
[40] "      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);"                                                                
[41] "    }"                                                                                                               
[42] "    catch(err) {"                                                                                                    
[43] "      var xslStylesheet = document.implementation.createDocument(\"\", \"\", null);"                                 
[44] "      xslStylesheet.async = false;"                                                                                  
[45] "      xslStylesheet.load(xslFile);"                                                                                  
[46] "      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);"                                                                
[47] "    }"                                                                                                               
[48] "    if (theColumn) {"                                                                                                
[49] "      xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,\"field\",\"f\" + (parseInt(theColumn) - 1));"                                 
[50] "      xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,\"datatype\",datatype);"                                                       
[51] "      xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,\"orderby\",orderby);"                                                         
[52] "    }"                                                                                                               
[53] "    var resultFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(window.opener.mv_XMLFileArray[themaId].XMLFile,document);"
[54] "    document.getElementById(\"content\").innerHTML = \"\";"                                                          
[55] "    document.getElementById(\"content\").appendChild(resultFragment);"                                               
[56] "  }"                                                                                                                 
[57] "}"                                                                                                                   
[58] "//-->"                                                                                                               
[59] "</script>"                                                                                                           
[60] "<title>Table attributaire</title>"                                                                                   
[61] "</head>"                                                                                                             
[62] "<body onload=\"sortTable();\">"                                                                                      
[63] "<div id=\"content\">Veuillez patientez ...</div>"                                                                    
[64] "</body>"                                                                                                             
[65] "</html>"                                                                                                             
[66] ""
```

any ideas ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
You can use the Inspect Element tool from Chrome to help you identify which types of calls clicking the table button will trigger.

And you can easily retrieve those data using this ajex call.

```
http://www.si-vitifrance.com/docs/cvi/cvi13/cartes_inter/c_vin01_coop_com07/embfiles/th0.xml
```

Then you can start parsing the html from there.

To parse xml or html, the `XML` will be a useful tool. Here is a POC of how to get the title based on the xpath of the element you want.

```
> library(XML)
> library(RCurl)
> url <- "http://www.si-vitifrance.com/docs/cvi/cvi13/cartes_inter/c_vin01_coop_com07/embfiles/th0.xml"
> doc = htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)
> title <- xpathSApply(doc, "//title[@id='titth0']", fun=xmlValue)
> title
[1] "Quantité livrée à la cave coopérative (hl)"
```

Python BeautifulSoup for scraping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "http://www.si-vitifrance.com/docs/cvi/cvi13/cartes_inter/c_vin01_coop_com07/embfiles/th0.xml"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
f0s = soup.find_all('f0')
for f0 in f0s:
    print f0.text
```

Output:

```
Commune
07- BOURG-SAINT-ANDEOL
07- VILLENEUVE-DE-BERG
07- LABLACHERE
... 
07- BERRIAS-ET-CASTELJAU
07- BESSAS
```

Comment: tank you !! related issue there is something for get a well formated data frame ? like xtable ?

Comment: @delaye are you asking for a magical function to turn the xml into a beautiful dataframe?

Comment: of course :-) R is beautiful ! any way thank you @B.Mr.W

Comment: @delaye, maybe you can take a look at BeautifulSoup in Python, I found that package much easier to work with. And Python is no less powerful than R. See update for the POC in bs4.

Comment: Tank you again @B.Mr.W :-)